# Creating an ALB Target Group in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to create an Application Load Balancer in CloudFormation, with a target group that forwards traffic to EC2 instances. Here is the relevant snippet, where ELBSubnets, ECSCluster, taskdefinition, and VpcId are passed in as parameters:

```json
"EcsElasticLoadBalancer" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
  "Properties" : {
    "Subnets" : { "Ref" : "ELBSubnets" },
    "SecurityGroups": [
      { "Ref": "ELBAccessSecurityGroup" }
    ]
  }
},
"LoadBalancerListener": {
  "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
  "Properties": {
    "DefaultActions": [{
      "Type": "forward",
      "TargetGroupArn": { "Ref": "TargetGroup" }
    }],
    "LoadBalancerArn": { "Ref": "EcsElasticLoadBalancer" },
    "Port": 80,
    "Protocol": "HTTP"
  }
},
"TargetGroup": {
  "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "Name": { "Fn::Join": [ "-", [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" }, "TargetGroup" ] ] },
    "Port": 80,
    "Protocol": "HTTP",
    "VpcId": { "Ref": "VpcId" }
  },
  "DependsOn": [ "EcsElasticLoadBalancer" ]
},
"service": {
  "Type": "AWS::ECS::Service",
  "Properties" : {
    "Cluster": { "Ref": "ECSCluster" },
    "DesiredCount": "1",
    "LoadBalancers": [
      {
        "ContainerName": "main-app",
        "ContainerPort": 3000,
        "TargetGroupArn": { "Ref": "TargetGroup" }
      }
    ],
    "Role" : {"Ref":"ECSServiceRole"},
    "TaskDefinition" : {"Ref":"taskdefinition"}
  }
},
"ECSServiceRole": {
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
  "Properties": {
    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": [
              "ecs.amazonaws.com"
            ]
          },
          "Action": [
            "sts:AssumeRole"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Path": "/",
    "Policies": [
      {
        "PolicyName": "ecs-service",
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer",
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress"
              ],
              "Resource": "*"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I get the following error when creating the service:

> The target group with targetGroupArn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:targetgroup/AlbServiceStack-TargetGroup/6ba9c037c26cdb36 does not have an associated load balancer.

What am I missing? In the documentation there doesn't seem to be a way to specify a load balancer for the target group.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Got it working - the problem was twofold:

1. The following lines were missing from the Role PolicyDocument:

   - `"elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets"`
   - `"elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets"`
2. The service needed `"DependsOn": [ "LoadBalancerListener" ]` as an additional attribute.

Updated template looks like this:

```json
"EcsElasticLoadBalancer" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
  "Properties" : {
    "Subnets" : { "Ref" : "ELBSubnets" },
    "SecurityGroups": [
      { "Ref": "ELBAccessSecurityGroup" }
    ]
  }
},
"LoadBalancerListener": {
  "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
  "Properties": {
    "DefaultActions": [{
      "Type": "forward",
      "TargetGroupArn": { "Ref": "TargetGroup" }
    }],
    "LoadBalancerArn": { "Ref": "EcsElasticLoadBalancer" },
    "Port": 80,
    "Protocol": "HTTP"
  }
},
"TargetGroup": {
  "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "Name": { "Fn::Join": [ "-", [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" }, "TargetGroup" ] ] },
    "Port": 80,
    "Protocol": "HTTP",
    "VpcId": { "Ref": "VpcId" }
  },
  "DependsOn": [ "EcsElasticLoadBalancer" ]
},
"service": {
  "Type": "AWS::ECS::Service",
  "DependsOn": [ "LoadBalancerListener" ],
  "Properties" : {
    "Cluster": { "Ref": "ECSCluster" },
    "DesiredCount": "1",
    "LoadBalancers": [
      {
        "ContainerName": "main-app",
        "ContainerPort": 3000,
        "TargetGroupArn": { "Ref": "TargetGroup" }
      }
    ],
    "Role" : {"Ref":"ECSServiceRole"},
    "TaskDefinition" : {"Ref":"taskdefinition"}
  }
},
"ECSServiceRole": {
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
  "Properties": {
    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": [
              "ecs.amazonaws.com"
            ]
          },
          "Action": [
            "sts:AssumeRole"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Path": "/",
    "Policies": [
      {
        "PolicyName": "ecs-service",
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer",
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets"
              ],
              "Resource": "*"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: DependsOn Attribute: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html

Comment: For me, the key was that the `AWS::ECS::Service` must have a `DependsOn` with both `LoadBalancerListener` *and* the `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup` must have `DependsOn` with `EcsElasticLoadBalancer`, which you do not call out in your twofold answer.  Also, I suggest you use the official AWS PolicyDocument `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole` rather than create your own.

Comment: `HTTP` is not a supported `Protocol` type for a listener.

Comment: I am very confused, wouldn't the LoadBalancer depend upon the TargetGroup, not the other way around? Since you have to have the TargetGroup made already when you go to create the LoadBalancer in the AWS Console (GUI)?