# Is it possible to do path based routing across different Elastic Beanstalk applications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

I have multiple elastic beanstalk applications running on AWS.

I would want to route certain paths to 1 application and another path to another application.

For example, any request going to example.com/app1 will be handled by the App1 whereas any request going to example.com/app2 will be handled by App2.

I tried creating a target group and then going to the application load balancer and add listener rules to them. However, the routing does not seem to work as it constantly times out.

How do I configure my load balancer to route my paths to the different elastic beanstalk apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AWS API gateway in-front of the Load Balancer to route the requests to your respective LB configured with AWS BeanStalk.

Proposed architecture document is shared here.

[image]